# Razor pages display value from pagemodel method

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages

This is my `razor pages` model class:

```cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IPaymentService _paymentService;
    private readonly ICategoryService _categoryService;
    
    public IEnumerable<PaymentEntity> Entities { get; set; } = default!;
    public IEnumerable<CategoryEntity> Categories { get; set; } = default!;
    public string GetCategoryName(int? id) => (id == null) ? "" : Categories.Single(x => x.Id == id).Name;

    public IndexModel(IPaymentService paymentService, ICategoryService categoryService)
    {
        _paymentService = paymentService;
        _categoryService = categoryService;
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Entities = await _paymentService.GetAll();
        Cities = new SelectList(await _categoryService.GetAll(), "Id", "Title");
    }
}
```

And this is how I am using this class in my view page:

```cs
@page
@model IndexModel

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Category name</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Entities)
    {
        <tr>        
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.GetCategoryName((item.Category_Id)))
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

But I am getting exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

in this line: `@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.CategoryName((item.Category_Id)))`. Any ideas what's wrong there? I think ASP.NET MVC5 has this feature as `RenderAction` method.

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend that create/modify your model for binding the category name in order to get rid of calling the method in HtmlHelper.

1. Create a model class for `PaymentEntity`.

```cs
public class PaymentEntityModel
{
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

    // Properties from PaymentEntity

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

2. Retrieve `Entities` list from the service, and at the same time bind the `CategoryName` value for each item.

```cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    ...
    
    public IEnumerable<PaymentEntityModel> Entities { get; set; } = default!;

    public string GetCategoryName(int? id) => (id == null) ? "" : Categories.Single(x => x.Id == id).Name;

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Entities = (await _paymentService.GetAll())
            .Select(x => new PaymentEntityModel
            {
                Category_Id = x.Category_Id,
                // Assign other properties
                CategoryName = x.Category_Id == null ? "" : Categories.Single(y => y.Id == x.Category_Id).Name
            });

        Cities = new SelectList(await _categoryService.GetAll(), "Id", "Title");
    }
}
```

3. Replace the `Model.CategoryName((item.Category_Id))` with `item.CategoryName`,

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Entities)
{
    <tr>        
        ...
            
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```